# How to insert an existing image into a table from another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert-image

i have a table include an image field, i need to insert that image field to another table like this :

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(select id,stdpic from student)
dt.Clear(); da.Fill(dt);
insert into team(teamid,teampic)values('"+dt.Rows[0][0].tostring()+"','"+dt.Rows[0][1].tostring()+"')
```

how to do it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. But, the image datatype has been deprecated for almost 15 years now, time to upgrade your schema. Also, you desperately need to use parameterized queries as this is wide open to sql injection.

Answer (score -1):

You are going to have to choose a new format, maybe a varbinary